# Assigning the data in the model class to the array and sending notification to the user according to the incoming data

Tags: java, android, json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Zek.png)I have two problems gradually, firstly, I want to pull the getDavaTarih field from the cases model class and assign it to an array

```
public class Davalar {

String davaTarihi, davaTuru, esasNo, kararNo, notlar, key;

public Davalar() {

}

public Davalar(String davaTarihi, String davaTuru, String esasNo, String kararNo, String notlar, String key) {
    this.davaTarihi = davaTarihi;
    this.davaTuru = davaTuru;
    this.esasNo = esasNo;
    this.kararNo = kararNo;
    this.notlar = notlar;
    this.key = key;
}

public String getDavaTarihi() {
    return davaTarihi;
}

public String getDavaTuru() {
    return davaTuru;
}

public String getEsasNo() {
    return esasNo;
}

public String getKararNo() {
    return kararNo;
}

public String getNotlar() {
    return notlar;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}
}
```

where I add data to the model class

```
public void davalariGetir() {
    databaseReference.child(userId).orderByChild("davaTarihi").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Davalar davalar = dataSnapshot.getValue(Davalar.class);
            if (davalarList.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey()) == -1) {
                davalarList.add(new Davalar(davalar.getDavaTarihi(), davalar.getDavaTuru(),
                        davalar.getEsasNo(), davalar.getKararNo(),
                        davalar.getNotlar(), davalar.getKey()));
            }

            textView_dava_ekle.setText("");
            image_view_ekle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            davalarAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            davalarList.remove(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            davalarAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

inside this function I want to add all the getDavaTarih fields to the string array
how can I do that ? then i will come to my other question

I want to take two fields shown in the model class in summary and assign them to string array

Comment: Are you able to fill the data in the `davalarList `? If yes then why do you need to add them to a String Array?

Comment: yes i can fill it there but after that, I want to take getDavaTarih and compare it with today's date and send a notification to the user. I would like to take the dates there one by one and compare with today and send a notification if there is 1 day left in the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What I understand from your comment is that you are trying to extract the `davaTarihi`, if that is the question:**

```
//after you filled the davalarList

for(int i=0 ; i<davalarList.size() ; i++){

//extract every davaTarihi and compare it with the current date

String davaTarihi = davalarList.get(i).getDavaTarihi();

//then notify whatever

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the method you said, but I have a problem. Although I have two records as shown in the pictures, there are three records in the log records. How can I fix this?

```
 public void davalariGetir() {
    databaseReference.child(userId).orderByChild("davaTarihi").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Davalar davalar = dataSnapshot.getValue(Davalar.class);
            if (davalarList.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey()) == -1) {
                davalarList.add(new Davalar(davalar.getDavaTarihi(), davalar.getDavaTuru(),
                        davalar.getEsasNo(), davalar.getKararNo(),
                        davalar.getNotlar(), davalar.getKey()));

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < davalarList.size(); i++) {
                davaTarihi = davalarList.get(i).getDavaTarihi();
                try {
                    convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
                    convertedDate2 = dateFormat.parse(davaTarihi);
                    Log.i("yyy", convertedDate2.toString());
                    Log.i("abc", convertedDate.toString());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (convertedDate.after(convertedDate2)) {

                    //TODO push notification
                    // OneSignal Initialization
                    OneSignal.startInit(DavalarimActivity.this)
                            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                            .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                            .init();

                }
            }


            textView_dava_ekle.setText("");
            image_view_ekle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            davalarAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            davalarList.remove(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            davalarAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt4pH.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrs1q.png

And wherever I put it in class, the list is empty, it just comes full where I write, but there is always more

> Blockquote